# Uniform distribution over a circle with random radius

Tags: probability

I know that  radius of disc is uniformly distributed over the interval $[a b]$ and I want  find the distribution function of the area of the disc.

I calculate $F(x,y)$ as integral of density function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Is it right? I can`t find suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the question in the title is different from the question in the body.

**The distribution of the area**

The distribution function of $R$, the radius, is

$$F_R(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$
if $a\leq x\leq b$, $0$ if $x<a$, and $1$ if $x>b$.

If $R$ is the random radius then the random surface area, $A$ is $\pi R^2$. The distribution function of the area is, by definition
$$F_A(x)=P(\pi R^2<x)=P\left(R<\sqrt{\frac x{\pi}}\right)=F_R\left(\sqrt{\frac x{\pi}}\right).$$

So$$F_A(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sqrt{\frac x{\pi}}-a}{b-a}&\text{ if }&a^2\pi\leq x\leq b^2\pi\\0&\text{ if }&x<a^2\pi\\1&\text{ if }& x>b^2\pi.\end{cases}$$ The density function is then
$$f_A(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(b-a)}\frac1{x^{\frac32}}$$
over  $[\pi a^2,\pi b^2]$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I didn`t think that distribution is uniform